# Magento 2 Ui Component Form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, uicomponent

I'm trying create one simple page with form without grid on Admin of Magento2, just one page with some fields.

I'm working with ***Model, ResourceModel, Collection and DataProvider and form ui_component.***

I tested the connection of my model with database and all is ok.

My problem is when i load the form page my fields don't pull the database content.
On **DataProvider** Class in **getdata** method, the collection `($this->collection->getItems())` show a empty array.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
Via form.xml it works directly with the url parameters.
That is, I just needed to put id / rownumber as a parameter (path) in the url that it would bring me the information of table row.